# How to ignore invalid options in getopt_long

Tags: c++, c, linux, getopt

I am using function `getopt_long` to get command line options. 
I want to ignore error when a invalid option is given. 
Currently it printing  error to stderr like:

```
 invalid option -- 's'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's variable `opterr` in getopt.h which will avoid printing the the error to `stderr`  if you set it to 0.

Just set it to 0:

```
extern int opterr;

opterr = 0;
```

Comment: Huh, you're right, it's possible. As I pointed out in my now deleted answer, this cannot work reliably: options may have arguments (`sed -e`), so for unknown options, it's not possible to determine whether the following argument should be interpreted as a new option, or as an argument to the invalid option. So while your answer is correct, I can't recommend using it unless you really know what you're doing and understand what sort of incompatibilities with future versions of your program you will encounter.

Comment: BTW, if you use this, you should just include `<unistd.h>`, not declare `opterr` manually.

Comment: This is simply to ignore the stderr printed by `getopts_long`, nothing more. Not sure what incompatibilities will arise. `opterr` is not a local variable. It's declared in getopt.h and can be optinally set as this case. I can't *see* deleted answers, not yet anyway :)

Comment: What I mean is that if a future version of the program accepts `-e` options with an argument, then that future version will treat `-e -i` as a single option (`-i` is the argument to `-e`), but the older version will treat it as an ignored `-e` option without an argument, and a separate `-i` option. Similarly, `-e x` would be treated as an argument `x` for the `-e` option in the new version, and an ignored `-e` option and a separate `x` command-line argument, which would typically be treated as a file name.

Comment: As for `<getopt.h>`, that's platform-specific. The POSIX header is `<unistd.h>`, and regardless of which of those headers you use, it should already declare `opterr` without your code having to say `extern int opterr;`. (`getopt_long` isn't part of POSIX (unless it has since been added), but `getopt` and its `opterr` which is used by `getopt_long` is.)